# css file not imported to webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to implement css modules in my typescript react project, but still can't get the css file imported:

[image]

- I use [css-modules-typescript-loader](https://github.com/seek-oss/css-modules-typescript-loader) to create .css.d.ts to assert typing
- I use [@dr.pogodin/react-css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules) to be able to use css modules ("styleName") in react. It'll generate some hash for the css property like the "src-containers-___App__background___2WjSL" in the image above

Here are the files regarding the App and css:

App.tsx:

```
import "./App.css";
//returns some jsx
<h3 styleName="background" className="background">CSS Here</h3>
//I also use react className to hope the css renders
```

App.css:

```
.background {
    color: pink;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

App.css.d.ts:

```
interface CssExports {
  'background': string;
}
export const cssExports: CssExports;
export default cssExports;
```

And Here are the configs, where I think the problem comes from:

webpack.config.ts:

```
import * as path from "path";
import * as webpack from "webpack";
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              "@babel/preset-react",
              "@babel/preset-typescript",
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-modules-typescript-loader" },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
          // {
          //   loader: "postcss-loader",
          //   options: {
          //     postcssOptions: {
          //       plugins: [
          //         [
          //           "postcss-preset-env",
          //           {
          //             // Options
          //           },
          //         ],
          //       ],
          //     },
          //   },
          // },
          // I don't know how they should be chained and what loader/options exactly to include
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    compress: true,
    port: 4000,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      async: false,
      eslint: {
        files: "./src/**/*",
      },
    }),
  ],
};

export default config;
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@dr.pogodin/react-css-modules", {
      "webpackHotModuleReloading": true
    }],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ],
  ]
}
```

If helpful:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@dr.pogodin/babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^6.0.7",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.26.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.0",
    "@types/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.5",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.24",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.2.6",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "css-modules-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "postcss": "^8.1.6",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.4",
    "precss": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

Any hint would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the generated hash name between `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` vs `css-loader` are now different in pattern.

In order to fix this, since `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` is now using this pattern `[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]` by default, you just fix by configure `css-loader` using the same pattern as following:

```js
{
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    modules: {
      localIdentName: '[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
    },              
  }
}
```